# Lightbox / Jquery Moleskine Notebook, javascript interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am wondering if anyone has any idea or can help me with a slight problem. (Head Code is below)

I am using Moleskine Notebook Jquery (Website notebook) and I am making a manga type comic for a Japanese company here. They want the pages to be images (Which is ok) but they want to click parts of the image with a lightbox style (pop-up gallery type style).

When I incorporate both codes, The javascript must interfere with each other, it does not work. Maybe because the image is inside a div for moleskine notebook? When I click the image which is linked to the lightbox div, it doesnt open lightbox, it just opens the image in a new page.

I have also tried to place the code differently in the head code. The light box down the bottom and the scripts up the top. So many different ways, always they interfere with each other.

Would anyone have any idea on how to make this work?

Cheers
Jess

```
    <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
            $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
            $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.booklet.1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="booklet/jquery.booklet.1.1.0.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />

    <script src="cufon/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cufon/ChunkFive_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cufon/Note_this_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Cufon.replace('h1,p,.b-counter');
        Cufon.replace('.book_wrapper a', {hover:true});
        Cufon.replace('.title', {textShadow: '1px 1px #C59471', fontFamily:'ChunkFive'});
        Cufon.replace('.reference a', {textShadow: '1px 1px #C59471', fontFamily:'ChunkFive'});
        Cufon.replace('.loading', {textShadow: '1px 1px #000', fontFamily:'ChunkFive'});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the colorbox.js file in your page and your calling colorbox before jQuery is even loaded. It won't work with just the colorbox css. Also, why such an old version of jQuery? Current version is 1.9.10